# Error in the program "error C3861: 'copyString': identifier not found", please tell me why?

Tags: c++

I'm new to programming, I was trying this program to copy one string into another string but it's showing error

```
 "error C3861: 'copyString': identifier not found"
```

Here is the code that I wrote

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char a[8], b[8];
    cout << "enter the string a";
    cin.get(a, 8);
    cout << a;
    int len = sizeof(a) / sizeof(char);
    copyString(a, b);
    int i;
    cin >> i;
    return 0;
}

/*function that copy one string to another*/

void copyString(char* a, char* b)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (a[i] != '\0') {
        b[i] = a[i];
        i++;
    }
    cout << b << " String is this";
}
```

Please tell me where am I mistaking??

Comment: forward declaration

Comment: Not your main problem but still needs to be fixed: `cin.get` does not read a null-terminated string. You need to manually add a null terminator (without overflowing buffer) before calling `copyString` which checks for a null terminator.

Comment: This question brings back memories!

Answer (score 2):

Either provide `copyString` implementation before `main`, or provide a prototype for it first:

```
void copyString(char *a,char *b); // prototype of copyString
int main()
{ 
    ...
}
void copyString(char *a,char *b)  // implementation of copyString
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: In this case I'd prefer to swap the order of the functions. Removes the possibility of making a change to the forward declaration but forgetting to do the same to the implementation.

Comment: @user4581301 agree, for this simple case we may not really need prototype. But for more longer source code, the prototype would really help reading.

Answer (score 2):

C++ compiler requires you to provide the declarations before a function or a variable is used. To solve your problem, you can simply place a forward declaration of copyString() before main().

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void copyString(char* a, char* b); // this is the forward declaration

int main()
{
    char a[8], b[8];
    cout << "enter the string a";
    cin.get(a, 8);
    cout << a;
    int len = sizeof(a) / sizeof(char);

    copyString(a, b);
    int i;
    cin >> i;
    return 0;
}

/*function that copy one string to another*/
void copyString(char* a, char* b)
{
    /* here is the real implementations */
}
```

However, when your program growth and more and more functions (with inter-dependence) are added, I would recommend you to split those functions into a separated header file and a source for easier maintenance.

*main.cpp*

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include "my_string_lib.h" // PLEASE notice this line

int main()
{
    char a[8], b[8];
    cout << "enter the string a";
    cin.get(a, 8);
    cout << a;
    int len = sizeof(a) / sizeof(char);

    copyString(a, b); // included in my_string_lib.h
    int i;
    cin >> i;
    return 0;
}
```

*my_string_lib.h*

```
#pragma once // assume you are using msvc

/*!
    Copy the string content from a to b, 
    assume b is allocated large enough to hold a.
*/
void copyString(char* a, char* b);
```

*my_string_lib.cpp*

```
#include "my_string_lib.h"

void copyString(char* a, char* b)
{
    /* here is the real implementations for copying a to b*/
}
```

Please make sure that *main.cpp, my_string_lib.cpp and my_string_lib.h* are placed inside the same directory.